# Order by field in redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

In MySQL I can do order by clauses among the lines of:

```
order by field(id,2,3,4,1)
```

I need to apply the same end result but on Redshift. The only thing I've been able to come with is:

```
order by case when 2 then 0
              when 3 then 1
              when 4 then 2
              when 1 then 3
              end
```

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order by` is already expensive so some additional string operations are not going to be particularly expensive.  You could do:

```
order by position(',' || id || ',' in ',2,3,4,1,')
```

Comment: I think it will always return zero, you're trying to find the position of `,,` in the given string, probably you forgot to put `id` between commas. Actually you don't even need these commas, it would work as `order by position(id::varchar in '2341')`?